# How to modify tab order in HTML for a dynamic focus sequence?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a web page with a specific tab order requirement. I have a set of tabs and a "More Info" button, and I want the tab order to behave as follows:

When a tab is clicked, the focus should go to

1. to the input with a class of `tab is-active`.
2. to "More Info" button
3. input elements within the section with the class of `inputs`
4. After last input element focus should move to next input with a class of `tab`.
5. And repeat from second point

Basically the idea is that, every input element with class of `tab` is a section of form elements, and requirement is to focus first on the elements of particular section and go back to the next input element with class of `tab`.
I've numerized the order of focus for better illustration.

I've tried using the tabindex attribute and JavaScript, but I can't get the behavior to work as intended.

So from my understanging I need to first skip the focus of the next input element with class of `tab`, and listen to the tab pressed events, and check if it is the last element, then add focus to next input with class of `tab`.

Here is markup structure, and obviously js is not working is expected.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabs {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tab-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-inline: 10px;
}

.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.more-info {
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="tabs">
      <input class="tab is-active" type="submit" value="First section 1." />
      <input class="tab" type="submit" value="Second section 5." />
      <input class="tab" type="submit" value="Third section " />
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <button type="submit" class="more-info">
        More Info 2.
      </button>
      <section class="inputs">
        <div class="item">
          Name 3.
          <input type="text" class="form-input" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          EMail 4.
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-input"
            placeholder="your.email@adress.com"
          />
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Here is [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-wnfvxl?file=/index.html), in case you want to play around.

Let me know if anythings is unclear and I'll try to update my question.

*NOTE* The amount of elements is not fixed. Furthermore there can be more elements than in the example, therefore adding tabindex directly to html markup is not a solution.

Comment: How did you attempt to use `tabIndex` and how did it not meet your expectations? Please include your attempt with that attribute in your question.

Comment: @mykaf check please the sandbox link, it includes js attempts.

Comment: All code needs to be in your question; links can break and are therefore rendered useless to future readers. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But I asked about `tabIndex`

Comment: Hey @mykaf thanks for pointing out my mistake. 
I updated my post adding the snippet of js part in the question.

Comment: I'm still not seeing any reference to the tabIndex attribute?

Comment: @mykaf you're right, it's not there. I didn't add it because was not working properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255790/discussion-between-mykaf-and-fd3).

Comment: Obligatory reminder that one must be **very careful** when altering tab order, as it can be confusing or frustrating for users relegated to assistive technology like screen readers and keyboard-only navigation.  You must have a compelling reason to change the default tab order, and be certain that it is still logical and usable.  You can learn more from [the WCAG 2.1's success criterion 2.4.5: focus order](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-order.html).

Comment: @AlexanderNied thanks for pointing out this. 
This a requirement from client, it has already be considered

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `tabindex` that seems to be working in a manner that matches your requirements as described.  You stated that it was not working for you, but did not share in what way it failed to work.  If this does not meet your needs, you may need to update your question to explain in what way it is insufficient.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabs {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tab-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-inline: 10px;
}

.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.more-info {
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="tabs">
      <input class="tab is-active" type="submit" value="First section 1." tabindex="1" />
      <input class="tab" type="submit" value="Second section 5." tabindex="5" />
      <input class="tab" type="submit" value="Third section " />
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <button type="submit" class="more-info" tabindex="2">
        More Info 2.
      </button>
      <section class="inputs">
        <div class="item">
          Name 3.
          <input type="text" class="form-input" tabindex="3" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          EMail 4.
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-input"
            placeholder="your.email@adress.com"
            tabindex="4"
          />
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, an obligatory reminder: one must be **very careful** when altering tab order, as it can be confusing or frustrating for users relegated to assistive technology like screen readers and keyboard-only navigation. You must have a compelling reason to change the default tab order, and be certain that it is still logical and usable. You can learn more from [the WCAG 2.1's success criterion 2.4.5: focus order](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-order.html).

Comment: Hi @Alexander Nied, I hope that it was as simple as you did. The amount of inputs and amount of input elements with the class of „tab“ can vary. So we need a dynamic solution

Comment: The markup is just an example.

Comment: Ah, OK-- it might make sense then to make more note of that in your question body then- your title mentions "dynamic" but then the question only notes that you need this specific order for specific markup, without stating that it needs to handle any arbitrary content in a given slide.  With that context more clearly stated in the question you'll be more likely to get answers that help you with your issue.  Thanks for providing this clarification.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that. 
I updated my post.